# does not show image of button if the format is svg

Tags: c#, wpf, svg

I want to use a svg file as an icon for a button, but I have an error that says: "The component cannot be found.

What should I use as a source?

I used this code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Click="Click">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="/my project;component/my folder/my icon.svg" />
        <TextBlock> add</TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Comment: I freaking love seeing old answers still helping people. :)

Comment: But they did not help me.

Comment: In case it is not clear, WPF does not provide image decoding from an SVG file. You would usually convert the SVG to XAML with an appropriate tool.

Comment: ☝️ What he said (he's usually right) :)

Comment: What are appropriate tools?

Comment: Quick search for '[svg to xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=svg+to+xaml)' should get you fixed up.